# DateTime field isnot working SOQL Query

Tags: soql, datetime

I have couple of Question on  datetime fields.

***Question 1: How to pass current month beginning date time and ending datetime in Apex***

Here I setted"July" Month start datetime and end date time values

```
   Datetime  currentStart=DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0);
   Datetime CurrentEnd= DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0);
```

If I pass these values in following query:

```
   Datetime  currentStart=DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0);
   Datetime CurrentEnd= DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0);

  String q = 'SELECT Id,' + 
        String.valueOf(titleField) + ',' + 
        String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(descriptionField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(whatIdField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(whoIdField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' FROM ' + 
        String.valueOf(sObjectName) + ' WHERE ' + 
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\'' +
        ' And ' + String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + '=\''+'Currentstart'+'\' And ' +
        String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + '=\''+'CurrentEnd'+'\'';
```

***Output from above Query:***

```
SELECT Id,Subject,StartDateTime,EndDateTime,Description,WhatId,WhoId,OwnerId 
FROM Event WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE And StartDateTime='2018-05-30 18:30:00' And EndDateTime='2018-07-30 18:30:00'
```

***Error Received:***

```
 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: value of filter criterion for field 'StartDateTime' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes
```

***Question 2:How to ressolve above(date time) error***

If I run below query for testing Purpose it will work:

I had given this Query for Example:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE CreatedDate >= 2014-07-20T01:02:03Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. 
Basically you have to get the current month method tostartofmonth as start and in end append month to 1 and -1 to days .
Once after that pls split the days year and month to string and convert that to datetime format.

```
   Date currentStart = System.Date.today().toStartOfMonth(); 
   Date CurrentEnd = currentStart.addMonths(1).addDays(-1);

   Integer sdy = currentStart.day();
   Integer smon = currentStart.month();
   Integer syr = currentStart.year();
   Integer edy = CurrentEnd.day();
   Integer emon = CurrentEnd.month();
   Integer eyr = CurrentEnd.year();
   string cdate = syr+'-'+'0'+smon+'-'+'0'+sdy+'T00:00:00Z';
   string edate = eyr+'-'+'0'+emon+'-'+edy+'T00:00:00Z';
   String q = 'SELECT Id,' + 
       String.valueOf(titleField) + ',' +
       String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + ',' +
       String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + ',' +
       String.valueOf(descriptionField) + ',' +
       String.valueOf(whatIdField) + ',' +
       String.valueOf(whoIdField) + ',' +
       String.valueOf(userField) + ' FROM ' + 
       String.valueOf(sObjectName) + ' WHERE ' + 
       String.valueOf(userField) + ' = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\'' +
       //' And ' + String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + '=\''+cdate+'\' And ' +
       //String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + '=\''+edate+'\'';

       ' And ' + String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + '>='+cdate+' And ' +
       String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + '<='+edate;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Error message carefully, for dates you don't need to enclose them in quotes.

```
String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + '=\''+'Currentstart'+'\'
```

gives you

```
StartDateTime='2018-05-30 18:30:00'
```

And what you need to get id `StartDateTime=2018-05-30T18:30:00Z`

So you can utilize the [DateTime.format()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) method to achieve this.

```
String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + '=' + Currentstart.format()
```

There are several implementations of the format() method, so choose the one that fits your needs.